# array type property shared between multiple objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

it could be old question but i still not able to understand the theory behind it.

we have

```js
function Test(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
Test.prototype.myArray = []; // I know if i move this to constructor it can resolve my problem
Test.prototype.what = function() {
  document.writeln("<br/>" + this.myArray);
}
Test.prototype.add = function() {
  this.myArray.push(this.name);
}

var a = new Test('Scott');
a.add();
a.what();

var b = new Test('Smith');
document.writeln("<br/>"  + b.myArray + " <= Check this one")
b.add()
b.what();
```

nobody touch b object array, why javascript engine get it from Class prototype why not it just take empty array belong to that object.

**EDIT:**

All the answers are correct, let change the type of property to primitive

```js
function Test(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
Test.prototype.primitive = 1;
Test.prototype.myArray = []; // I know if i move this to constructor it can resolve my problem
Test.prototype.what = function() {
  document.writeln("<br/>" + this.myArray + " primitive:" +this.primitive);
}
Test.prototype.add = function() {
  this.primitive++;
  this.myArray.push(this.name);
}

var a = new Test('Scott');
a.add();
a.what();

var b = new Test('Smith');
document.writeln("<br/>"  + b.myArray + " primitive:" +b.primitive +" <= Check this one now primtive is not shared")
b.add()
b.what();
```

So conclusion is all reference types attached to top prototype are shared to all instances and **primitive datatypes like number are not.**

Comment: This is how property lookup in javascript works. When you write  `a.myArray` engine first checks if `a` has a property named `myArray`. Since it doesn't engine goes up the prototype chain. So, whenever you are accessing `myArray` (using whatever starting object sharing the same prototype) you will get the same array unless you define `myArray` property on the object itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why javascript engine get it from Class prototype why not it just take empty array belong to that object.

That's just how prototypical inheritance works. As you only assigned one array to the prototype object's property, instead of an array to every instance (like it happens if you create an assign in the constructor), there simply *is no empty array belonging to the object* and the property lookup goes to the prototype.

Comment: this is not true in case of primitive datatypes, right?

Comment: @A.T.: inheritance for properties that hold primitive values works the same as for properties that hold objects. The only difference is that primitive values can be shared without problems, as you don't modify them (like you do with the array in the question).

Comment: @A.T.: Notice that `this.primitive++` is equivalent to `this.primitive = this.primitive+1`, an assignment, which creates an own property on the instance. It would work the same with your array if you did `this.myArray = this.myArray.concat([this.name]);`

Comment: oh good catch, that's confusion...why i missed that. thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

> nobody touch b object array, why javascript engine get it from Class prototype why not it just take empty array belong to that object

That's the way prototype works in javascript.  We have an `object` and we have its `prototype`.
An important fact here is that when you create a new object, it doesn't copy all the properties and methods of the prototype.
It actually have a reference to the `prototype` object and the property / method resolution is performed dynamically.

For example, if you ask the object to return a `myArray` property, javascript does this:

- Does `object` have `myArray`? No (since you didn't declare this.myArray)
- Does `object.prototype` has `myArray`? Yes
- Return `object.prototype.myArray`

Now if you create two `Test` objects, they actually have the same prototype and refer to the same `prototype.myArray` property:

```
      ------------------
      | Object a       |
      |                |                 ---------------------
      | name = 'Scott' |                 |                   |
      | prototype  ----|---------------> |   prototype       |
      ------------------                 |                   |
                                         |   myArray = []    |
      ------------------                 |                   |
      | Object b       |                 |                   |
      |                |                 |                   |
      | name = 'Smith' |                 |                   |
      | prototype  ----|---------------> |                   |
      ------------------                 ---------------------
```

Since both `a` and `b` have the same `prototype`, they also refer to the same `myArray`.
This way the modification of this array via `a` or `b` will change it for both objects.

**Update**: in the case when `prototype` has a primitive value, it is still shared between `a` and `b`:

```
Test.prototype.primitive = 1
a = new Test();
a.primitive; // 1
b = new Test();
b.primitive; // 1

// Update prototype's primitive
Test.prototype.primitive += 1
// a and b objects refer to the updated value
a.primitive; // 2
b.primitive; // 2
```

But when you do something like `a.primitive++` or, more explicitly, `a.primitive = a.primitive + 1`, you actually create the `primitive` property in the `a` object and it doesn't refer to the `prototype` anymore:

```
// Now a.primitive is actually created in the a object and
// does not refer to the prototype anymore
a.primitive++;
a.primitive; // 3
Test.prototype.primitive; // 2
b.prototype.primitive; // 2

// Now prototype primitive updates will only affect object b
Test.prototype.primitive += 2;
a.primitive; // 3
b.prototype.primitive; // 4
```

Comment: @A.T. I am not 100% sure and need to re-check this, but I think when you update the primitive value, it can create an actual copy of it inside the object. So after update you have an own copy of the `primitive` inside the object and it becomes disconnected from the `prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

because you are adding to the `Test` when you do `Test.prototype.myArray` not to the instance of test. Just keep it in `this.myArray`

replace your code with

```
function Test(name) {
  this.name = name; this.myArray = []; //observe this change
}
Test.prototype.what = function() {
  console.log("<br/>" + this.myArray);
}
Test.prototype.add = function() {
  this.myArray.push(this.name);
}
var a = new Test('Scott');
a.add();
a.what();
var b = new Test('Smith');
console.log("<br/>"  + b.myArray + " <= Check this one")
b.add()
b.what();
```

Answer (score 0):

**prototypes** in JavaScript  are used as  **fallbacks**.
Meaning that  if the object in question doesn't have the requested  member(method or property), the prototype of the current object is queried to find that member.
If it is not there the upper prototype is queried and this process is going up until it reaches the **Object** prototype Which is the base prototype in JavaScript.

Here is an example :

```
var test1,test2,test3;

Object.prototype.getInfo = function(){
    return this.firstName + " - " + this.lastName;
}

function test1(){
    this.firstName = "ham";
}

test2.prototype = test1;
function test2(){
    this.lastName = "bam";
}

test3.prototype = test2;
function test3(){
    return this.getInfo();
}

test1(); // at this level firstName property is available
test2(); // at this level firstName,lastName  properties are available
test3(); // returns 'ham - bam' because the main prototype Object has the method getInfo and we have firstName,lastName from the previous prototypes.
```

When reaching the **Object** prototype, if the requested member still not found, an error is thrown.

Here is the [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ismnoiet/qLt1zdw2/)

Hope this hepls.